# Getting Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /myurl/ error while Overriding JSONWebTokenAPIView post method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-rest-framework-jwt

I inherit ObtainJSONWebToken and trying to override the post method of JSONWebTokenAPIView but every time I hit API It throws me error : Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /myurl/

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import ObtainJSONWebToken

class LoginDrfJwtView(ObtainJSONWebToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(ObtainJSONWebToken, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if condition == True:
            # my code
        return True
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login-jwt-over/', views.LoginDrfJwtView),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an authentication class to this class-based view that bypasses CSRF check. The CSRF error happens to views that do not have any authentication classes defined.

You'll need to create an authentication class that inherits from SessionAuthentication and always returns. It can be something like the following:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication

class CsrfExemptAuth(SessionAuthentication):

    def bypass_csrf(self, request):

        return
```

Then, in you view, the add to the authentication_classes.

`authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptAuth,)`

Comment: Thank you! Which `authentication_classes` should I use? I have tried `authentication_classes = ()` but thats not working.

Comment: I have updated my main answer so I can add a readable code snippet. Please try it out and let me know.